# Is there a way to suppress FindBugs from generating warnings on code generated by static weaving?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm getting what I think are false positives from FindBugs (2.0.2) and Sonar (3.7.3) on code that is being generated via static weaving of EclipseLink (2.5.1) JPA entities.  Specifically, I am seeing multiple occurrences of

```
ES_COMPARING_PARAMETER_STRING_WITH_EQ
Comparison of String parameter using == or != in com.test.domain.MyEntity._persistence_set(String, Object)
```

and

```
URV_INHERITED_METHOD_WITH_RELATED_TYPES
Inherited method com.test.domain.MyEntity._persistence_get(String) returns more specific type of object than declared
```

Is there a way to eliminate these warnings for the code generated by EclipseLink without having to globally disable the rules or exclude analysis on the entities entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good question! Since your issues originate with FindBugs, you can use [FindBugs exclusion filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) to address this. Especially, take a look at the `<Method>` exclusion. You can specify a regex that matches the method names of your getters and setters in the entity classes, such as

```xml
<Method name="~_persistence_[gs]et" />
```

Such a filter file can be used by all forms of FindBugs, including the Eclipse plugin and SonarQube. For example, using the SonarQube ant task, you can set the property `sonar.findbugs.excludesFilters` to the absolute path to the FindBugs exclusion file.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  It looks like Sonar 4 has more options for managing exclusions/patterns from the console but nothing as granular as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at exclusions: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus